# How to append a readable stream to from data and post

Tags: node.js, stream

I am a new nodejs stream. I want to create a stream in server A, that can store the file after parsing a multipart/form-data request, and then append the stream to another form to post to server B.

But whent I receive the request in server B, the content-length of the request header is much small than the file size and it throw error "Parse Error, stack: Error: Parse Error".

Can someone tell me what is wrong? Thank you very much!

Here is my code,
body-parse.js----a middleware to parse req and create a stream to store buffer

```
async function formHandler2(req, res, next) {
    const contentType = req.headers['content-type'] || ''
    if (contentType.indexOf('multipart') === 0) {
        try {
            let form = new formidable.IncomingForm({ multiples: true })
            req.body = req.body || {}
            form.onPart = function(part) {
                let isField = false,
                    buffers = []
                if (!part.filename) {
                    console.log(` ****** formidable field ***** ${part.name}`)
                    isField = true
                } else {
                    console.log(` ****** formidable files ***** ${part.name} ${part.filename}`)
                }

                this._flushing++
                const readableStream = new stream.Readable({
                    highWaterMark: 64 * 1024, // 64KB
                })

                // this.emit('fileBegin', part.name, file)
                part.on('data', (buffer) => {
                    if (buffer.length == 0) {
                        return ''
                    }
                    if (isField) {
                        buffers.push(buffer)
                    } else {
                        readableStream.push(buffer)
                    }

                    //this.pause()
                    //this.resume()
                })
                part.once('end', () => {
                    if (isField) {
                        req.body[part.name] = Buffer.concat(buffers).toString()
                        console.log(
                            ` ****** formidable field ***** ${part.name} ${req.body[part.name]}`
                        )
                    } else {
                        if (!req.body[part.name]) {
                            req.body[part.name] = []
                        }
                        console.log('----------- readableStream end')
                        readableStream.push(null)
                        readableStream._readableState.sync = false
                        console.log(readableStream._readableState.buffer)
                        req.body[part.name].push(readableStream)
                    }

                    this._flushing--
                    // this.emit('file', part.name, file)
                    this._maybeEnd()

                    // req.body[part.name].push(stream)
                    //part.resume()
                })

                part.on('error', (err) => {
                    console.log('part parse error', err)
                })
            }

            form.on('end', function() {
                console.log('Upload completed!')
                next()
            })

            form.parse(req)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('formHandler', err)
            res.send({
                success: false,
                message: err.message ? err.message : err,
            })
        }
    } else {
        if (is.empty(req.body)) {
            req.body = is.empty(req.query) ? null : req.query
        }
        next()
    }
}
```

addPersonnel.js----post a form to server B

```
          const RP = require('request-promise')

    async function add(req, res) {
        try {
            const username = req.session.username
            const { UID, SID, name, description, personType, avatars } = req.body
            const newPersonnel = await RP({
                url: URL.personnel.add,
                method: 'POST',
                formData: {
                    UID,
                    SID,
                    name,
                    description,
                    personType,
                    avatars
                }
            })
            res.send({ success: true, newPersonnel })
        } catch (err) {
            res.goError({ error: err })
        }
    }
```

Here is the request info logged in server A,

```
{ method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3500/v1/personnel/new',
  formData: 
  { UID: '5aeac7413872ec3ae93f1d71',
    SID: '5aeac7643872ec3ae93f1d73',
    name: 'a',
    personType: 'staff',
    description: '',
    avatar: 
      [ Readable {
          _readableState: 
          ReadableState {
            objectMode: false,
            highWaterMark: 65536,
            buffer: 
              BufferList {
                head: 
                { data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 08 06 06 07 06 05 08 07 07 07 09 09 08 0a 0c 14 0d 0c 0b 0b 0c 19 12 13 0f ... >,
                  next: 
                    { data: <Buffer 0d>,
                      next: 
                      { data: <Buffer 20 ef fd 69 17 4f c5 ac 69 fa d4 25 ed 65 ff 00 0f 9b e4 b9 5c 65 19 08 e7 35 7f 4f 75 b5 8d d5 b4 76 5a c8 9a 29 23 e0 4f 1a ee 0c 3e a3 b8 ad 2b f5 ... >,
                        next: null } } },
                tail: 
                { data: <Buffer 20 ef fd 69 17 4f c5 ac 69 fa d4 25 ed 65 ff 00 0f 9b e4 b9 5c 65 19 08 e7 35 7f 4f 75 b5 8d d5 b4 76 5a c8 9a 29 23 e0 4f 1a ee 0c 3e a3 b8 ad 2b f5 ... >,
                  next: null },
                length: 3 },
            length: 14047,
            pipes: null,
            pipesCount: 0,
            flowing: null,
            ended: true,
            endEmitted: false,
            reading: false,
            sync: false,
            needReadable: false,
            emittedReadable: true,
            readableListening: false,
            resumeScheduled: false,
            destroyed: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            awaitDrain: 0,
            readingMore: false,
            decoder: null,
            encoding: null },
          readable: true,
          domain: null,
          _events: {},
          _eventsCount: 0,
          _maxListeners: undefined } ] }
}
```

As you can see, buffer length: 14047. However, at server B, content-length: '789',which is much smaller than the file. Plus, an error was thrown: message: Parse Error, stack: Error: Parse Error.

```
{ token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJrZXkiOiI2NW51Zjk4Z2ZvOGN1djhsaHQ4NDFuZDRvYmhqbzM4OWIzOG1rOGphIiwic2FsdCI6ImQwMTd1aHA0ZXZsZzBxcW03bzNoc3JlbTRqaTJwMjdpIiwiYWNjb3VudCI6Im1lbmdxaWhlQHR1cHV0ZWNoLmNvbSIsIlVJRCI6IiIsImlhdCI6MTUzNDc3MjM0OCwiZXhwIjoxNTM0Nzc5NTQ4fQ.y8Izt85VnL9eMEn4O34CfddZJcGMqhCwUMKocKZQiiY',
  'ref-user': 'mengqihe@tuputech.com',
  host: 'localhost:3500',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------650686709075962079495394',
  'content-length': '789',
  connection: 'close' }
```

I have been stucked here for a few days... What is wrong with my code?